I need a RegEx to extract all characters in a string after 2 leading zeros. This includes alpha-numeric characters
Here is an example of the string.  I need to pull everything after the leading zeros.
0000099123
0000199110
ACH0615555
00000A9999

I would want to pull back the following:
99123
199110
A9999

I've tried the following expressions:
,[^0\n\r]*$


To get those results, you could use a capture group:
^.*?0{2,}(\S+)

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
.*? Match any character zero or more times, as few as possible
0{2,} match 2 or more zeroes
(\S+) Capture group 1, match 1 or more non whitespace chars (Or use .+ to also match spaces)

See a regex demo

If there are only leading zeroes:
^0{2,}(\S+)


When I use this, I'm still picking up the leading zeros.

There can be multiple leading zeros.

@HermanLewis How or where are you using this? You need the group 1 value.

I am using a SAAS tool.  It allows for users to use RegEx to pull data out of a filed.

@HermanLewis Do you know if there is documentation about this tool? If you can specify a group, then often they are denoted as \1 or $1 Other options could be ^0{2,}\K.+ or (?<=^0{2,})[^0].* but those are more  specific

I don't have any documentation for this tool.  I tried the "^0{2, }\K.+" expression and it almost works.  I don't think the tool likes the "K." argument.

@HermanLewis You could try a lookbehind assertion (?<=00)[^0].*

If you want to use the acquisition group, excluding the group with zeros (thus obtaining the result in group 1), you can use this:
(?:0{2,})(\w+)

If you prefer not to use capture groups and have the match without leading zeros, you can use this regular expression with negative lookahead (but it also accepts a single leading zero):
(?!0+)(\w*)

\w    Matches a single word character (letters, numbers, and underscore)
